# I need to execute a function() when clicking a button on GoogleDoc sidebar

Tags: javascript, html, google-apps-script, google-docs, sidebar

I have already created a very simple sidebar on my Google Doc as an Add-on. But, since I am not so advanced as I wanted in this matter, I'm stuck. This sidebar has simply a textbox and a button where the user would enter a string text, then simply click the button to 'execute a function' (and here is where I need help).

I have the function and it worked! But, I don't know how to build the script to execute the function by the sidebar's button.

I've made some research in this matter, and what I found didn't do anything nor gave any error messages. It just won't work. If you guys know where can I find here a former question that achieves my goal, please let me know! If not, please tell me how to do it.

Here's the html file code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!-- Use this CSS stylesheet to ensure that add-ons styling
matches the default Google Docs styles -->
<link href="https://ssl.gstatic.com/docs/script/css/add-ons.css"
rel="stylesheet">

<!-- The sidebar will have a input box and the search button -->
<div class="sidebar">

<!-- The search box -->
<div class="block form-group">
<input type="text" id="url_text" placeholder="Enter DB spreadsheet url" />
<button class="blue" id="search_phrases">Search Phrases</button>
</div>

<!-- Load the jQuery library from the Google CDN -->
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>

<script>
// Attach click handlers after the Sidebar has loaded in Google Docs
$(function() {

// Here is my problem----------------------------------------
$('#search_phrases').click(function() {
higlightPhrases($('#url_text').val())
});

// If the user presses the Enter key in the search box, perform a search
$('#url_text').keyup(function(e) {
if (e.keyCode === 13) {
$('#search_phrases').click();
}
});

});
</script>
```

And, my function is the following (within a script file):

```js
 function higlightPhrases(db_url) {
     // For comfortable reasons, I've reduced the function script into a message.
     DocumentApp.getUi().alert(db_url);
 }
```

Thanks for your help!
AJ

Comment: *ve made some research in this matter, and what I found didn't do anything nor gave any error messages.* What did you find? Did you read the relevant section of the official apps script documentation: "Client server communication"? See [tag info page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/google-apps-script/info) for more details.

Comment: Hello @TheMaster! Thanks for your comment! As I mentioned, I'm not so advanced (may be I don't even get to the basics!) however, I appreciate what you shared, and I found the solution! I just had to call it this way! **google.script.run.higlightPhrases($('#url_text').val())**
Thank you very much!

Comment: Consider adding it as a answer in the answerbox below. see [answer]

Comment: Thank you very much! I surely will.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to close the post with an answer, as @TheMaster commented above, I was recommended to see

> the relevant section of the official apps script documentation: "Client server communication"? See [info page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/google-apps-script/info) for more details.

And so, I've fixed my code like this:

```html
// Here is(was) my problem----------------------------------------
$('#search_phrases').click(function() {
google.script.run.higlightPhrases($('#url_text').val())
});
```

Thank you! @TheMaster