# Sidebar button onClick in Google docs script doesn't fire

Tags: google-apps-script, web-applications, google-docs

I'm trying to mechanize calling a docs script routine from a button click (see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66502487/add-a-clickable-menu-item-or-a-button-to-the-google-docs-editor)).  It seems the only way to do this is to create a sideboard for the document.

Here's my script:

```
function CreateSideBar ()
{
Logger.log ('CreateSideBar Entry')
var HTML = HtmlService.createHtmlOutput ('<button onClick="CallFromSidebarButton () ;">Do It!</button>').setTitle ('My Sidebar') ;
DocumentApp.getUi ().showSidebar (HTML) ;   
Logger.log ('CreateSideBar Exit')
}

function onOpen() 
{
CreateSideBar ()  
}


function CallFromSidebarButton ()
{
var ui = DocumentApp.getUi () ; 
ui.alert ('Call from sidebar OK') ;  
}
```

Things work fine if I call them from the script debugger, but if I open the document, the sidebar creates OK, but nothing happens when I click on the button.

Inspection shows:

```
userCodeAppPanel:1 Uncaught ReferenceError: CallFromSidebarButton is not defined
    at HTMLButtonElement.onclick (userCodeAppPanel:1)
```

The doc is shared [here](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1ZawkLSxQhmO9iQiHFX69x-lduhkq5lU6k0Mabij12IM/edit?usp=sharing). You will probably need to be signed in and agree to a bunch of stuff.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To call a server side function from client side code you have to use `google.script.run` i.e. replace

```
var HTML = HtmlService.createHtmlOutput ('<button onClick="CallFromSidebarButton () ;">Do It!</button>').setTitle ('My Sidebar') ;
```

by

```
var HTML = HtmlService.createHtmlOutput ('<button onClick="google.script.run.CallFromSidebarButton () ;">Do It!</button>').setTitle ('My Sidebar') ;
```

Resources

- https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/web
- https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/dialogs
- https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/communication

Related

- [I need to execute a function() when clicking a button on GoogleDoc sidebar](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61146562/1595451)

Comment: Works a treat - many thanks for the answer and resources.  I'm puzzled as to how the original code that *doesn't* work is able to work when executed in the debugger - is that not client-side also?